# Greatest Common Divisor With large numbers

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Find $\gcd(300^{40},2^{57})$
I know how to use Euclidean Algorithm for smaller numbers, but with these large numbers I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Note that $300^{40}$ is divisible by $2^{80}$.

Comment: This might help: $300^{40}=(2^8+2^5+2^3+2^2)^{40}$

Answer (score 2):

Prime Factorize Each: $$300^{40}=2^{80}3^{40}5^{80}$$ $$2^{57}=2^{57}$$.

Thus, notice that $2^{57}|300^{40}$, and so the $\gcd$ is $2^{57}$.

In general, when approaching the $\gcd(a^{b}, c^{d})$, the easiest method would be to factorize $a$ and $c$.